# Awk/Unix group by

Tags: unix, awk

have this text file:

```
name, age
joe,42
jim,20
bob,15
mike,24
mike,15
mike,54
bob,21
```

Trying to get this (count):

```
joe 1
jim 1
bob 2
mike 3
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1{arr[$1]++}END{for (a in arr) print a, arr[a]}' file.txt
joe 1
jim 1
mike 3
bob 2
```

### EXPLANATIONS

- `-F,` splits on `,`
- `NR>1` treat lines after line 1
- `arr[$1]++` increment array `arr` (split with `,`) with first column as key
- `END{}` block is executed at the end of processing the file
- `for (a in arr)` iterating over `arr` with `a` key
- `print a` print key `, arr[a]` array with `a` key

Comment: +1 for a one line awk answer (which was the tag in the question)! I love learning here...

Comment: Any comment why "mike" is printed before "bob", when the first occurrence of "bob" is before "mike" in the file?...

Comment: Arrays are arbitrarily sorted in `awk`. So, the output order is not guaranteed.

Comment: I see now, NR skips the 1st line, everything after END runs only once. thx!

Comment: A small modification allows you to SUM the ages instead of just counting records: `awk -F, 'NR>1{arr[$1]+=$2}END{for (a in arr) print a, arr[a]}' file.txt'`

Answer (score 30):

Strip the header row, drop the age field, group the same names together (sort), count identical runs, output in desired format.

```
tail -n +2 txt.txt | cut -d',' -f 1 | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $1 }'
```

output

```
bob 2
jim 1
joe 1
mike 3
```

Comment: +1 for for fast and compact answer! I was only halfway through... And you give it in alphabetical order (wasn't asked...)

Comment: We'll see how OP wants it sorted, if at all. (To sort by the count, stick a `sort -n` before the `awk`).

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you want sorted output. You could simply pipe or print into `sort -nk 2`:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1 { a[$1]++ } END { for (i in a) print i, a[i] | "sort -nk 2" }' file
```

Results:

```
jim 1
joe 1
bob 2
mike 3
```

---

However, if you have `GNU awk` installed, you can perform the sorting without coreutils. Here's the single process solution that will sort the array by it's values. The solution should still be quite quick. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}

NR>1 {
    a[$1]++
}

END {
    for (i in a) {
        b[a[i],i] = i
    }

    n = asorti(b)

    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        split (b[i], c, SUBSEP)
        d[++x] = c[2]
    }

    for (j=1;j<=n;j++) {
        print d[j], a[d[j]]
    }
}
```

Results:

```
jim 1
joe 1
bob 2
mike 3
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1 { a[$1]++ } END { for (i in a) b[a[i],i] = i; n = asorti(b); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) { split (b[i], c, SUBSEP); d[++x] = c[2] } for (j=1;j<=n;j++) print d[j], a[d[j]] }' file
```

Answer (score 4):

A strictly awk solution...

```
BEGIN { FS = "," }
{ ++x[$1] }
END { for(i in x) print i, x[i] }
```

If `name, age` is really in the file, you could adjust the awk program to ignore it...

```
BEGIN   { FS = "," }
/[0-9]/ { ++x[$1] }
END     { for(i in x) print i, x[i] }
```

Comment: Liking the use of the /[0-9]/ address to work only with lines with an age in it...

Answer (score 0):

I come up with two functions based on the answers here:

```sh
topcpu() {
    top -b -n1                                                                                  \
        | tail -n +8                                                                            \
        | awk '{ print $12, $9, $10 }'                                                          \
        | awk '{ CPU[$1] += $2; MEM[$1] += $3 } END { for (k in CPU) print k, CPU[k], MEM[k] }' \
        | sort -k3 -n                                                                           \
        | tail -n 10                                                                            \
        | column -t                                                                             \
        | tac
}

topmem() {
    top -b -n1                                                                                  \
        | tail -n +8                                                                            \
        | awk '{ print $12, $9, $10 }'                                                          \
        | awk '{ CPU[$1] += $2; MEM[$1] += $3 } END { for (k in CPU) print k, CPU[k], MEM[k] }' \
        | sort -k2 -n                                                                           \
        | tail -n 10                                                                            \
        | column -t                                                                             \
        | tac
}
```

```sh
$ topcpu
chrome           0    75.6
gnome-shell      6.2  7
mysqld           0    4.2
zsh              0    2.2
deluge-gtk       0    2.1
Xorg             0    1.6
scrcpy           0    1.6
gnome-session-b  0    0.8
systemd-journal  0    0.7
ibus-x11         6.2  0.7

$ topmem
top              12.5  0
Xorg             6.2   1.6
ibus-x11         6.2   0.7
gnome-shell      6.2   7
chrome           6.2   74.6
adb              6.2   0.1
zsh              0     2.2
xdg-permission-  0     0.2
xdg-document-po  0     0.1
xdg-desktop-por  0     0.4
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -d',' -f 1 file.txt |
sort | uniq -c
```

```
2 bob
1 jim
1 joe
3 mike
```