# count, groupby with sed, or awk

Tags: awk, sed

i want to perform two different sort and count on a file, based on each line's content.
1. i need to take the first column of a `.tsv` file
i would like to group by each line that starts with three digits, and keep only the three first digits, and for everything else, just sort and count the whole occurrence of the sentence in the first column.

Sample data:

```
687/878 9
890987  4
01a 55
1b  8743917
890a    34
abcdee  987
dfeqfe  fkdjald
890897  34213
6878853 834
32fasd  53891
abcdee  8794371
abd 873
```

result:

```
687 2
890 3
01a 1
1b  1
32fasd  1
abd 1
dfeqfe  1
abcdee  2
```

I would also appreciate a solution that would

also take into account a sample input like

```
687/878 9
890987  4
01a     55
1b      8743917
890a    34
abcdee  987
dfeqfe  545
890897  34213
6878853 834
(632)fasd  53891
(88)abcdee  8794371
abd     873
```

so the first column may have values like (,), #, ', all kind of characters

so output will have two columns, the first with the values extracted, and the second with the new count, with the new values extracted from the source file.

Again preferred output format tsv.

so i need to extract all values that start with 
^\d\d\d, and then for these three first digits, sort and count unique values,

but in a second pass, also do the same for each line, that does not start with 3 digits, but this time, keep the whole columns value and sort count by it.

what i have tried:
`| sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` for the lines that do start with ^\d\d\d, and

the same for those that do not fulfill the above regex, but is there a more elegant way using either `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Awk/Unix group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916826/awk-unix-group-by)

Comment: Why is this more complex? I only see one level of groups.  Briefly, `awk -F '\t' '/^[0-9]{3}/ { a[substr($1,1,3)]++; next } { a[$1]++ } END { etc etc }'`

Comment: there are two groups, one that has the values ^[0-9]{3}, and one that has the whole values of all the rest lines, that do not match ^[0-9]{3}

Comment: i would also appreciate an awk or sed approach

Comment: then you shouldn't have accepted the first answer you got as that discourages people form providing additional answers since you may not even be reading them any longer.

Comment: Those groups are in the same array; just print it in the `END` block.

Comment: I see no requirement for separate sorting. The fact that Ed's answer is accepted suggests that this is acceptable. If there are additional requirements, probably a new question would be the way to go at this point.

Comment: @tripleee  Two passages from OP's description, starting from `so i need to` -- Near the end.

Comment: Then use two different arrays.

Comment: I still don't see that this is a clear requirement. Feel free to post a new question if you need help figuring this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{ cnt[/^[0-9]{3}/ ? substr($1,1,3) : $1]++ }
END {
    for (key in cnt) {
        print (key !~ /^[0-9]{3}/), cnt[key], key, cnt[key]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -k1,2n | cut -f3-
687     1
890     2
abcdee  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Perl

```
$ cat nefijaka.txt
687     878     9
890987  4
890a    34
abcdee  987
$ perl -lne  ' /^(\d{3})|(\S+)/; $x=$1?$1:$2; $kv{$x}++; END { print "$_\t$kv{$_}" for (sort keys %kv) } ' nefijaka.txt
687     1
890     2
abcdee  1
$
```

You can pipe it to sort and get the values sorted..

```
$ perl -lne  ' /^(\d{3})|(\S+)/; $x=$1?$1:$2; $kv{$x}++; END { print "$_\t$kv{$_}" for (sort keys %kv) } ' nefijaka.txt | sort -k2 -nr
890     2
abcdee  1
687     1
```

EDIT1:

```
$ cat nefijaka.txt2
687     878     9
890987  4
890a    34
abcdee  987
a word and then 23
$ perl -lne  ' /^(\d{3})|(.+?\t)/; $x=$1?$1:$2; $x=~s/\t//g; $kv{$x}++; END { print "$_\t$kv{$_}" for (sort keys %kv) } ' nefijaka.txt2
687     1
890     2
a word and then 1
abcdee  1
$
```

Comment: just pipe ````| sort -k2 -nr````. Check my updated answer

Comment: the above looks good, if only i could sort results not by keys, but by occurrences found, and if it could take into account that i also have a space in certain word values. ie. aa bb cc

Comment: you mean "aa bb cc" like "abcdee" in the sample input?

Comment: 'abcdee' one value, and 'one sentence with spaces in it' a second value in the input. or the sentence could have any characters

Comment: the OP doesn't mention that there will be 2 groups.. there is some type in the first line..the \ is \t

Comment: @stack0114106 Two passages from OP's description, starting from `so i need to` -- Near the end.

Comment: yes, two passages, two groups, but i accepted the answer since i would like to try refine the solution myself before getting a ready answer :)

Comment: @nefijaka .. appreciate that you wanted try on yourself

Comment: @nefijaka.. please provide sample input for the 2 group scenario.. I'll update the asnwer to that as well

Comment: @nefijaka.. could you please add the expected output?.. I tried Ed's solution.. its all printing 1,1,...so I'm little confused.